# Replacing an object in list with a list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have an object as shown below:

```
public class School 
{

 public string schoolName { get;set;}
 public List<ClassRoom> classAttribute{get;set;}
}

public class ClassRoom 
{
 public string Duster{get;set;}
 public string BlackBoard {get;set;}
 public List<Students> students {get;set;}
}

public class Students 
{
  public int StudentID {get;set;}
  public string StudentName {get ;set;}
  public string Weight {get;set;}
  public string Height {get;set;}
}
```

I also have a **dict** of `Type <key,CustomObject>` where the `CustomObject` contains all of the `"Students"` class fields plus additional fields.

```
public class CustomObject
{
  public string HairColor {get;set;}
  public int StudentID {get;set;}
  public string StudentName {get ;set;}
  public string Weight {get;set;}
  public string Height {get;set;}
  public string Ethnicity {get;set;}
}
```

I have got the dict built in such a way that `key` is the `StudentName` and `Value` is the `CustomObject`
like

```
dict<Key,CustomObject> dict 
QuickWatch
Key : Student1
Value: [0] :

      HairColor : Black 
      StudentID : 1
      StudentName : Student1
      Weight : 58
      Height : 89
      Ethnicity : Asian
[1] :

      HairColor : Brown
      StudentID : 2
      StudentName : Student1
      Weight : 24
      Height : 22
      Ethnicity : Arfican
```

I have a **School** object where the Students list

```
List<Students> studentList = new List<Students>();
```

just has "`StudentName`" in the inner `Students` Object and other fields are empty. I have to find this `StudentName` in the Dictionary
and build the "`Students`" Object from the "`CustomObject`" and then attach it to "`ClassRoom`" . So finally I should be able to get all the fields filled for the `Student` object(2 Student objects from my example above ,one with HairColor as black and one with Haircolor as brown) when I expand the `School` object in the immediate window and navigate to "`School`",data coming from dictionary.

. In the example, One student having 2 PropertyObjects is just hypothetical only.

How would I continue getting the result. Is it something like :

```
studentList.Select(x => x.classAttribute)
           .Select(y => y.students)
           .Where(z=>z.StudentName == dict.key);
```

But the problem is I have to build `Student` Object  from `CustomObject` before attaching it also. So, how I do it with linq?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
var result = school
                .classAttribute
                .SelectMany(c => c.students)
                .Where(s => s.StudentName == "some dict key")
                .Select(s => new CustomObject
                {
                    StudentID = s.StudentID,
                    StudentName = s.StudentName,
                    Height = s.Height,
                    Weight = s.Weight
                }).Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
       school
            .classAttribute
            .SelectMany(ca=> ca.students)
            .SelectMany(s=> s.students)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(student =>
            {
                // Get data from dictionary and update properties
                student.Weight = "data from dictionary";
                student.Height= ""data from dictionary;
            });
```